# Content security policy and Safari

Tags: safari, content-security-policy

I have `Content-Security-Policy` header on my site available by HTTP protocol with value

```
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.googlesyndication.com
```

and it works well except Safari browser under Mac that refuses to load 
scripts from http://googlesyndication.com via HTTPS protocol

How can I make CSP works for Safari?

Comment: Bump! I have this issue too. I read somewhere that Safari doesn't support the domain without the protocol on the front but I can't find any official documentation to confirm that. I'll run tests just as soon as I can find a mac I can use.